# Simple text translation depending on store view

Tags: magento-1.7, module, extensions, csv, localisation

I am creating a simple module that displays a date.
 I need the days (Monday, Tuesday, etc.) to be translated in the store view language. 
 
 I've gotten lost in all the different ways that this could be done:
1) Where should I create the `.csv` file? (preferably in my module, if that's at all possible)
 2) How would I tell Magento which words to translate? I'm currently using the `indexcontroller.php` to display the date (In case that changes something).
 Can someone guide me through this or suggest a tutorial that I might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this step-by-step:

**1 -** On your module on the file called `config.xml` set the csv file to translate:

```
<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <modulename>
                <files>
                    <default>Package_Modulename.csv</default>
                </files>
            </modulename>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
<admin>
<translate>
    <modules>
        <modulename>
            <files>
                <default>Package_Modulename.csv</default>
            </files>
        </modulename>
    </modules>
</translate>
</admin>
```

**2 -** Create your file, for example:

```
app/local/en_US/Package_Modulename.csv
```

**3 -** Apply on code like these samples:

```
$this->__('My Extension')
```

or

```
Mage::helper("myhelper")->__('My Extension')
```